# Undefined reference?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks

A simple program but for some reason it can't run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "simpio.h"
int main()
{
float kop;
kop = GetReal();
printf("%d",kop);
    return 0;
}
```

it says undefined reference to 'GetReal' and 'getInteger' and the other

the compiler I guess is not in the right place

Comment: can you point where GetReal is defined?

Comment: That's a linker error — it means you've not included the library (or object file(s)) that define `GetReal()` on the command line that links the program.  Including the header declares the existence of the function to the compiler.  But the linker needs to know where the functions are defined.

Comment: Once you have fixed that part, switch from `printf("%d",kop);` to `printf("%f",kop);`

Comment: @IłyaBursov It's presumably in the library that corresponds to `simpio.h`

Comment: the library is linked correctly